# How to return AcceptedAtRouteResult from an Azure function?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, .net-standard

I keep on getting unhandles host errors when returning `AcceptedAtRouteResult` from an Azure function.

I want to be able to return an `AcceptedAtRouteResult` from an Azure Function to tell the caller the default values of any omitted query string parameters, but I keep getting unhandled host errors.

I'm targeting .net Standard 2.0.3 and using `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.26`

```cs
[FunctionName("AcceptedAtRouteResult")]
public static IActionResult AcceptedAtRouteResult(
    [HttpTrigger("GET")]HttpRequest req)
{
    // read query parameter if present else set to defualt value

   var rs = new AcceptedAtRouteResult(
        "acceptedatrouteresult", 
        new { someParameter = "value" }, 
        new { Result = "1" });

    return rs;
}
```

I keep on getting an exception:

> An unhandled host error has occurred. System.Private.CoreLib: Index
>   was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the
>   collection. Parameter name: index.

Comment: I reproduced the issue and I believe that is a bug within the runtime. You can track the status of the bug report here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4267

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product team recomended using the following class to replace an AcceptedAtRouteResult return type until the bug can be corrected:

```
class AcceptedObjectResult : ObjectResult
{
    private readonly string _location;

    public AcceptedObjectResult(string location, object value) : base(value)
    {
        _location = location;
    }

    public override Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 202;
        var uri = new UriBuilder(context.HttpContext.Request.Scheme, context.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host)
        {
            Path = $@"api/{_location}",
        };
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Host.Port.HasValue)
        {
            uri.Port = context.HttpContext.Request.Host.Port.Value;
        }

        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add(@"Location", uri.ToString());

        return base.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
    }
}
```

The bug ticket can be tracked on Github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4267

Comment: I have the same problem with CreatedAtRouteResult

Comment: If you are getting the same error than it is probably the same bug- you could add a comment to the Github thread to let the product team know that there are multiple types affected. If it's the same bug then the same workaround should work in the meantime.

Comment: I filed a PR to fix this issue but it's worth noting that if you're using `AcceptedAtRoute` or `CreatedAtRoute` you **must** have a Function defined that maps to the route you're returning in the `Location` header. This is in line with what ASP.Net does. If you want to point the consumer to a place outside the boundary of your Function app, you must used `AcceptedResult` or `CreatedResult` and not their "Route" or "Action" counterparts.